# How configure the HTTP Headers in Weblogic Response

Tags: weblogic

Using WebLogic 11g and want to be able to add headers to all files served up by WebLogic.

There is no separate web server sitting in front of WebLogic.

Cannot find a way to configure WebLogic to add header to the HTTP response.

In IIS you can easily do this by choosing the server and clicking to add headers. Looking for the equivalent way to do this in WebLogic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think this is configurable. You would have to write a  [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to manipulate the headers as you need.

As a hint, you could try something along the lines of this package http://flavio.tordini.org/http-headers-filter. I have not tried this myself

Comment: I would prefer not to take the Filter approach if possible-- I need something that I dont have to deploy with the application. If thats what I will have to do then I'll do it, but again my preference would to be able to do something that's external to the application. can I stick a proxy in between the server and the clients browser that can add http hearders? I'm really only looking for something temporary to test out the effect of adding somethign to the HTTP header.

Comment: For a temporary solution to be able to modify response headers without modifying the code base, the free tool Fiddler also works well

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of putting Apache server in front of your Weblogic server, then you can configure Apache to do that using [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html). As an additional benefit, you can configure the Apache server to serve static content.

PS: Not just Apache but [Lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv) and [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) also allow you to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<url-rewriting-enabled></url-rewriting-enabled>
```

1. Can occur zero or one time.
2. When this flag is set to false, WebLogic will add the following header with the response `Cache-control: no-cache=set-cookie` so that the proxy caches do not cache the cookies.
3. defaults to true

http://w3processing.com/Setups.php?freepageId=19