# How add transport header in weblogic (CORS)?

Tags: weblogic, soa, weblogic11g

I work with Oracle SOA Suite and need to add one transport header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

In the configuration the server weblogic for get this:

[image]

This picture is of one service in IIS7, that he have the next configuration:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,SOAPAction,origin" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

How I do this in weblogic server?

For default in the browser with WebLogic shows this:

[image]

Comment: Did you check what is the default value showing up for this header for any SOA service running on weblogic?

Comment: Yes, In the second image is show. @amishra

Comment: I do not think it is possible at weblogic level. Although you can set it from inside the web service or if you have a http server in front of weblogic, you can set it there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306444/how-configure-the-http-headers-in-weblogic-response

Comment: You might need this one: http://www.ateam-oracle.com/oam-protected-spas-and-same-origin-policy/

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set the property 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' inside your webservice

This might help you :

https://techgrit.blogspot.com/2018/09/enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html